# How to get a JSON String from JSONObject?

Tags: java, json

I want to get a JSON String from the created JSONObject, which looks like a String when you want to create a JSONObject from that String.

I can write a method, I just cannot believe there isn't have a better solution.

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JSONString {

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.append("symbol", "AAPL");
    jsonObject.append("price", "211.17");

    // this is the String what I want to get from the jsonObject variable
    String wantedResultString = "{\n" +
                "  \"symbol\" : \"AAPL\",\n" +
                "  \"price\" : 211.17\n" +
                "}";


}
```

Comment: You mean like calling `toString()`?

Comment: Have you taken a look at any documentation or tutorial at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
String jsonObjectString = jsonObject.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("symbol", "AAPL");
        jsonObject.put("price", 211.17);
        System.out.println(jsonObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `put()` instead of `append()`and the use `jsonObject.toString()`

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("symbol", "AAPL");
        jsonObject.put("price", "211.17");
        System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
    }

}
```

output:

```
{"symbol":"AAPL","price":"211.17"}
```